# vanilla T4 DAL template and poco generation

Tags: code-generation, t4

I'm looking for T4 templates to generate completely vanilla poco and dal classes for a database table.

the poco should have a get, set for each column of the table.  columns which aren't required should be represented with nullable types

The dal get method should use a datareader to return an IEnumerable

Comment: Did you find anything?  I'm worried that EF will be too slow for my needs and am considering having a code-generated DAL instead.

Answer (score 0):

This video demonstrates an approach similar to what you are seeking: [Julie Lerman's video on Using the POCO T4 Code Generation with the Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/Video/ff717739)

Most people use the Entity Framework these days instead of datareaders. However, the T4 templates are customizable. You could modify the T4 DAL template to use a datareader instead of the Entity Framwork.